# hyperref \href underlined vertical spacing

Tags: tables, hyperref, underline

I am trying to underline links using `\href` from `hyperref` in a tabular environment, with an increased vertical spacing. As you can see in the MWE and the picture following it, it results in a line quite distant from the text, which is not aesthetically optimal and does not match the same link in the text body.

How can I reduce the vertical spacing between the link and the line? I have tried using `\smash` as suggested in other questions, but it does not solve the issue.

I could create a command to manually underline a link, like `\newcommand{\ul}[2]{\underline{\href{#1}{#2}}}`, but I guess there are more elegant solutions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}

\begin{document}
    
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    
    \href{https://www.google.com}{Link}
    
    \begin{tabular}{r}
        \href{https://www.google.com}{Link} \\
        \href{https://www.google.com}{\smash{Link}} \\
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectangle of a link is calculated by pdftex from the enclosing box, which for tabulars always contains a \strut. You can use \mbox to get a smaller box:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

    \href{https://www.google.com}{Link}

    \begin{tabular}{r}
        \mbox{\href{https://www.google.com}{Link}} \\
        \href{https://www.google.com}{\smash{Link}} \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]